# How to extract assigned value from a variable which is part of the json using JSON_EXTRACT funtion in mysql

Tags: mysql, json-extract

Hope, I was able to put the question in right way.

here I have a following table in mysql DB.

**Table Name:** Company

| OrgName | config |
| --- | --- |
| TestCompany | {orgld=24,Sector:IT) |

How to form a mysql query to extract **orgId value** present in the config column using JSON_EXTRACT funtion

Please note that I have formed a dummy data, which represent the actual data present in my org's DB

I did try running following query and tried to google, but was with no luck.

```sql
select 
  OrgName,
  (JSON_EXTRACT(config,"$.orgid")) as org_id
from
  Company;
```

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: PS. The value shown on the screenshot is **NOT** valid JSON. Eigher heal your data or extract needed value using common string functions.